# auto adjustSize()

Tags: qt, layout

my widget has children widgets which can appear and disappear sometimes.
Now after hiding one of child I call `adjustSize()` to resize the main widget to possible minimum.

How to automatically call `adjustSize()` when showing/hiding children in a layout?
I tried setting `sizePolicy` to `QSizePolicy::Minimum` but this doesn't help...

Answer (score 1):

When you call

```
QWidget::setVisibility(true/false)
QWidget::hide()
QWidget::show()
```

it generates a showEvent or a hideEvent see doc [here](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qwidget.html#visible-prop). So, what you could do is to install an eventFilter on your widget to check when the showEvent is called and then call adjustSize when it is required.

See doc [here](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qobject.html#installEventFilter) for details about the event filter.

Hope that helps.